# Search WordPress using static html page

Tags: php, search, forms, html

So I have a .html page under my Wordpress website and I want to be able to use the search button on the static html page to search the `search.php` page, is that possible?

Is this correct? This is located inside my `test.html`:

```
<div class="search_bar-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="search_bar search-input evt-search-input-wp" placeholder="Search"
    value="<?php echo get_search_query(true); ?>"/>
    <button class="btn-fh btn-secondary search-btn search-btn-overlay">
        <i class="custom-icon icon-icon_small_arrow_right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="clearInput"><img src="/images/icon_close.svg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Would I need to point a `form="submit"` and `action=".."` on the input instead? If so, what would the action need to point too?

Comment: `search.php` doesn't actually perform a search, all the searching is done and finished long before `search.php` is loaded, it just displays the results afterwards. Infact you can have a theme with only an `index.php` template and search will still function

Answer (score 2):

If you want to submit a form you need a `<form>` element to contain the input. (You can get away without one but you'd need script to fake the submit.) The action is the homepage with the search text in an input named 's', e.g.

```html
<form method="get" action="https://example.com/">
    <input type="search" name="s" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

for a bare-bones form. Or you can use [`get_search_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) to get a version with all of the ARIA attributes set up too.